# ASP.Net Impersonation to pass connection string to SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql, authentication, impersonation

I am building a webpage using Visual Studio 2013 that I want to run internally on my intranet (IIS 8.5) and take advantage of windows authentication or NTLM.

My webpage needs to contain SQL Server connection strings but I want the connection to SQL Server to use the currently logged in user that I can get via windows authentication.

I know that I need to use impersonation to achieve this but I am not sure how, is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

I know my `web.config` needs to contain

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several pieces that need to be configured in order to achieve this:

- IIS must be configured for integrated auth
- Enable "Identity Impersonate" (you've done this)
- Set `Trusted_Connection=Yes` in the connection string
- Add the appropriate users to the database

Here's an MSDN article that goes into more detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bsz5788z(v=vs.100).aspx